# How do I form a feature vector for a classifier targeted at Named Entity Recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, language-agnostic, nlp

I have a set of tags (different from the conventional Name, Place, Object etc.). In my case, they are domain-specific and I call them: Entity, Action, Incident. I want to use these as a seed for extracting more named-entities.

I came across this paper: "*Efﬁcient Support Vector Classiﬁers for Named Entity Recognition*" by Isozaki et al. While I like the idea of using Support Vector Machines for doing named-entity recognition, I am stuck on how to encode the feature vector. For their paper, this is what they say:

> For instance, the words in “President George Herbert Bush said Clinton
>   is . . . ” are classiﬁed as follows: “President” = OTHER,  “George” =
>   PERSON-BEGIN, “Herbert” = PERSON-MIDDLE, “Bush” = PERSON-END, “said” =
>   OTHER, “Clinton” = PERSON-SINGLE, “is”
>   = OTHER. In this way, the ﬁrst word of a person’s name is labeled as PERSON-BEGIN. The last word is labeled as PERSON-END. Other words in
>   the name are PERSON-MIDDLE. If a person’s name is expressed by a
>   single word,  it is labeled as PERSON-SINGLE. If a word does not
>   belong to any named entities, it is labeled as OTHER. Since IREX de-
>   ﬁnes eight NE classes, words are classiﬁed into 33 categories.
>
> Each sample is represented by 15 features because  each word has three
>   features (part-of-speech tag, character type, and the word itself),
>   and two preceding words and two succeeding words are also used for
>   context dependence. Although infrequent features are usually removed
>   to prevent overﬁtting, we use all features because SVMs are robust.
>   Each sample is represented by a long binary vector, i.e., a sequence
>   of 0 (false) and 1 (true). For instance, “Bush” in the above example
>   is represented by a vector x = x[1] ... x[D] described below. Only
>   15 elements are 1.

```
x[1] = 0 // Current word is not ‘Alice’ 
x[2] = 1 // Current word is ‘Bush’ 
x[3] = 0 // Current word is not ‘Charlie’

x[15029] = 1 // Current POS is a proper noun 
x[15030] = 0 // Current POS is not a verb

x[39181] = 0 // Previous word is not ‘Henry’ 
x[39182] = 1 // Previous word is ‘Herbert
```

I don't really understand how the binary vector here is being constructed. I know I am missing a subtle point but can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bag of words lexicon building step that they omit.

Basically you have build a map from (non-rare) words in the training set to indicies.  Let's say you have 20k unique words in your training set.  You'll have mapping from every word in the training set to [0, 20000].

Then the feature vector is basically a concatenation of a few very sparse vectors that have a 1 corresponding to a particular word, and 19,999 0s, and then 1 for a particular POS, and 50 other 0s for non-active POS.  This is generally called a one hot encoding.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot

```
def encode_word_feature(word, POStag, char_type, word_index_mapping, POS_index_mapping, char_type_index_mapping)):
  # it makes a lot of sense to use a sparsely encoded vector rather than dense list, but it's clearer this way
  ret = empty_vec(len(word_index_mapping) + len(POS_index_mapping) + len(char_type_index_mapping))
  so_far = 0
  ret[word_index_mapping[word] + so_far] = 1
  so_far += len(word_index_mapping)
  ret[POS_index_mapping[POStag] + so_far] = 1
  so_far += len(POS_index_mapping)
  ret[char_type_index_mapping[char_type] + so_far] = 1
  return ret

def encode_context(context):
  return encode_word_feature(context.two_words_ago, context.two_pos_ago, context.two_char_types_ago, 
             word_index_mapping, context_index_mapping, char_type_index_mapping) +
         encode_word_feature(context.one_word_ago, context.one_pos_ago, context.one_char_types_ago, 
             word_index_mapping, context_index_mapping, char_type_index_mapping) + 
         # ... pattern is obvious
```

So your feature vector is about size 100k with a little extra for POS and char tags, and is almost entirely 0s, except for 15 1s in positions picked according to your feature to index mappings.

Comment: +1 This is what I had in mind. Thank you very much for the clarification. On a related note, am I right in understanding that this approach is used for recognizing new named-entities as well? I posted a more general question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219915/how-do-i-approach-this-named-entity-classification-task but if this approach works for what I want to do, then I would rather go with SVMs. Any suggestions from your side would be great.